# Devise with mobile mime type, 401 only displays flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, devise, rails-routing

I have a Rail 3.2.2 app with Devise 2.0 that I've begun to incorporate mobile views with. I'm using a `before_filter` in my `application_controller.rb` to use the mobile layout as follows:

```
  before_filter :adjust_format_for_mobile

  private
    def adjust_format_for_mobile
      if request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"][/(iPhone|iPod)/] 

         request.format = :mobile
      end
  end
```

I have the mime type defined in `initializers/mime_types`:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
```

Whenever I attempt to access the `root_path` as defined in `routes.rb`:

```
root :to => "wells#index"
```

(which is protected via `before_filter :authenticate_user!`)

All that is rendered is the Devise flash message (no HTML whatsoever):

`You need to sign in or sign up before continuing`

I have the necessary mobile layout, what am I missing here? The behavior on the desktop version is that you're redirected to the `new_user_session_path`, why is that not the case here?

EDIT:

The console log is as follows:

```
   Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-21 17:07:35 -0500
   Processing by WellsController#index as HTML
   Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
```

Additionally, this only occurs with that particular path (the root path). If I manually go to users/sign_up or users/sign_in it works perfect. I can then log in and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a wiki on the process:

[How To: Make Devise work with other formats like mobile, iphone and ipad (Rails specific)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Make-Devise-work-with-other-formats-like-mobile,-iphone-and-ipad-(Rails-specific))